# <iframe> is blacked out in Google Chrome Mobile

Tags: html, google-chrome, iframe

I have created a Rails app. In which I have included an iframe tag which loads an embed link from [Box](https://www.box.com/). While testing on computer it works just fine[image: page on computer/desktop], but on actual devices, the video in iframe doesn't work. It  is blacked out [image: page on actual device] However, it works on UC browser.

Answer (score 0):

In order to allow the iFrame to work cross domain, you can change the default headers to allow X-Frame across domain.

```
config.action_dispatch.default_headers = {
    'X-Frame-Options' => 'ALLOWALL'
}
```